# Table Output in Sql

Tags: sql, reporting-services, db2

I have a query output as below.

```
Name   Price ProductTypeCode
Ram    120   P1
RAM    130   P1
RAM    140   P1
RAM    240   P1
RAM    340   P1
RAM    190   P2
RAM    160   P2
```

I want to Arrange the above output as:

```
Name   P2Price P1Price
Ram    190     120
RAM    160     130
RAM    null    140
RAM    null    240
RAM    null    340
```

Please help me to achieve the above output.

Comment: Please let us know which RDMS you are working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` to enumerate the prices.  Then pivot the data.  The following query does this using conditional aggregation:

```
select name,
       max(case when producttypecode = 'p2' then price end) as p2price,
       max(case when producttypecode = 'p1' then price end) as p1price
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name, producttypecode order by name) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
group by name, seqnum;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I am using DB2. Will it be possible to use the above syntax for DB2?

Comment: The above query returns only max price. But my output requires to show all P1 prices under one column and show P2 prices in other columns so that P2 prices rows will become columns. Simply as mentioned in my question, I need to convert P1 and P2 product prices to display column wise instead of rowwise.

Comment: @sarayucm . . . Oops, I left the `seqnum` out of the `group by`.  That part is pretty important.  And yes, this syntax should work in DB2.

Comment: 1+, This should be best answer for DB2 . I don't know how to delete my answer. :(

Answer (score 0):

Following Query will return your expected result regardless of DB2 version.

```
SELECT name,
       CASE WHEN producttypecode = 'p2' THEN price END AS p2price,
       CASE WHEN producttypecode = 'p1' THEN price END AS p1price  
       FROM YourTable
```

You may also try(depends on DB2 version):

```
SELECT NAME,
   DECODE(producttypecode , 'p2', price) AS p2pricel,
   DECODE(producttypecode , 'p1', price) AS p1price
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: The above query returns only max price. But my output requires to show all P1 prices under one column and show P2 prices in other columns so that P2 prices rows will become columns. Simply as mentioned in my question, I need to convert P1 and P2 product prices to display column wise instead of rowwise