# How do I create a query that returns a list of customers (by name) and their revenues and visits by month

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, recordset

noob to SQL. I have to create a query that returns a list of customers (by name) and their revenues and visits by month. Unfortunately, I don't have much of a clue how to do this, as the book for my class didn't cover anything similar to this. Here is what I have come up with so far... I think I'm close but I really don't know what to do next!

```
SELECT customer_first_name, customer_middle_initial, customer_last_name, 
price – cost as revenue, datepart(mm,date) as Month COUNT(receipt_number) 
as Visits 
FROM Customers, invoice4477 
WHERE Customers.customer_id = invoice4477.customer_id 
GROUP BY Visits 
ORDER BY customer_last_name desc
```

Can you help point me in the right direction? Using noob-speak? I really don't have a clue what I'm doing. The records I used already are the only ones really relevant in the database for this question. I just don't understand how to order the number of visits and the revenues per visit by month.

Additionally, I don't have a means of testing out the code as I don't have the actual database, just a screenshot of the tables (this is the real problem, otherwise I could probably troubleshoot it until I found an answer).

[image: Tables]

I think I want the output to look like this:

```
Customer Name    Revenue    Visits    Month
Joe Bob          $100       2         January
Joe Bob          $34        1         February
Sally Sue        $2443      5         January
Sally Sue        $243       4         June
```

Please help! Thank you :)

Comment: you need to `group by` all of the things you referred to in your 'by xxx' statements. ie 'by name' = `group by name`. 'by month' = `group by month`. combined, `group by name, month`. That said, you'd be better off grouping by customer_id, in case two customers have the same name

Comment: Several comments:  (1) You are using SQL Server syntax, but the question is tagged MySQL.  (2) You can use SQL Fiddle as an online database to try things out.  (3) Hopefully your book and class taught good practices, such as using explicit `join` syntax and spelling out "month" in `datepart()`.  (4) Your `group by` is missing a bunch of columns from the `select`.

Comment: Sorry about that, but the lack of my knowledge means I don't even know the difference between SQL server syntax and MySQL. My book has taught me none of these things; I had to Google how to even grab the month from the date record, as this wasn't mentioned in the book. So... how exactly should I format the Group By? Using customer name and month? That's what I don't get.

Comment: What table is `receipt_number` in? Also, I hope you don't have 4476 other invoice tables :)

Comment: receipt_number is in invoice4477. Oh gosh, if there were 4476 more I would kill myself :)

Comment: No need for suicide. If there were 4476 more...there is a way to query that too. Folks might find it easier to answer if you could determine your DBMS ( SQL Server, MySQL, etc...) And post your table definitions.

Comment: Best comments for today about the 4476 tables LOL. @KristySnyder Help us to hep you so consider in adding real data examples and from that example your desired result like this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29527663/460557

Comment: This screenshot is all I have to go off of: http://imgur.com/ONfqda2     My professor didn't even specify whether to use SQL Server or MySQL... he's not very verbose when it comes to instructions.

Comment: Ok, I added in the image of the data and the output table... hopefully that is helpful!

Comment: Seconding the comment to use SqlFiddle.com  SOOOO easy.  You can pick one of several different databases to use.  If It were me I'd choose Sql Server, but MySQL is also there.

Answer (score 1):

This works for **Oracle PL/SQL**

```
 SELECT Customer
        , Month
        , COUNT(ReceiptNo) AS Visits
        , SUM(Revenue) AS Revenue
   FROM (SELECT customer_first_name || ' ' || customer_middle_initial || '. ' ||  customer_last_name as Customer
                , to_char(date, 'Month') AS Month
                , invoice4477.cost - invoice4477.price as Revenue
                , receipt_number AS ReceiptNo
           FROM Customers 
                INNER JOIN invoice4477 ON Customers.customer_id = invoice4477.customer_id)
  GROUP BY Customer, Month;
```

**Schema** : The Column Names differ in my example

```
create table x(REC_NO int, CUST_ID int, RDATE date, price int, cost int);
create table cust (cust_id int, fname varchar2(20)
                   , mname varchar2(20), lname varchar2(20));

insert into x (rec_no, cust_id, rdate, price, cost) values
              (100, 1, to_date('08/04/2015','dd/mm/yyyy'), 150, 200);
insert into x (rec_no, cust_id, rdate, price, cost) values
              (101, 2, to_date('08/03/2015','dd/mm/yyyy'), 70, 80);
insert into x (rec_no, cust_id, rdate, price, cost) values
              (102, 1, to_date('07/01/2015','dd/mm/yyyy'), 50, 90);
insert into x (rec_no, cust_id, rdate, price, cost) values
              (103, 3, to_date('07/02/2015','dd/mm/yyyy'), 10, 200);
insert into x (rec_no, cust_id, rdate, price, cost) values
              (104, 3, to_date('07/01/2015','dd/mm/yyyy'), 10, 200);
insert into x (rec_no, cust_id, rdate, price, cost) values
              (104, 3, to_date('09/01/2015','dd/mm/yyyy'), 29, 200);              
insert into cust (cust_id, fname, mname, lname) values
              (1, 'john1','x', 'doe');
insert into cust (cust_id, fname, mname, lname) values
              (2, 'john2','x', 'doe');
insert into cust (cust_id, fname, mname, lname) values
              (3, 'john3','x', 'doe');
```

**SQL**

```
SELECT CNAME
       , RMonth as Month
       , SUM(REVENUE) as Revenue
       , COUNT(REC_NO) as Visits
  FROM (SELECT fname || ' ' || mname || '. ' || lname as CName
               , to_char(RDATE, 'Month') AS RMonth
               , x.cost - x.price as Revenue
               , REC_NO
          FROM cust INNER JOIN x ON cust.cust_id = x.CUST_ID)
  GROUP BY CNAME, RMonth;
```

**The result I got is as below**

```
|        CNAME |     MONTH | REVENUE | VISITS |
|--------------|-----------|---------|--------|
| john1 x. doe | April     |      50 |      1 |
| john2 x. doe | March     |      10 |      1 |
| john3 x. doe | February  |     190 |      1 |
| john3 x. doe | January   |     361 |      2 |
| john1 x. doe | January   |      40 |      1 |
```

Now, please be mindful that this might not be the feasible way to do this, but this works.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a T-SQL solution. Try it out and let me know if it needs any tweaks.

```
SELECT  C.customer_first_name,
        C.customer_last_name,
        CONCAT('$',SUM(I.price)) AS Revenue, --not sure whether you wanted price or cost
        COUNT(*) AS Visits,
        DATENAME(MONTH,I.[date]) AS [Month]
FROM Customers C
INNER JOIN invoice4477 I
ON C.CustomerID = I.CustomerID
GROUP BY C.CustomerID,C.customer_first_name,C.customer_last_name,DATENAME(MONTH,I.[Date])
```